# How to place jQuery Validate error message after the label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate and need to place the error message AFTER the label element. Currently, it's just inserting it after the input and before the element.

Can someone tell me how do this?

```
<td>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="text">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
</td>

errorElement: "div",
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    $(element).after(error);
},
```

Comment: `$(element).next().after(error);` ?

Comment: @Stack 101: That worked. Please add it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may help

```
$(element).next().after(error);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/sparkup/behLgebw/